# Is there a way to update common files across multiple branches in Git?

Tags: git, github

So currently I have two branches in my repository, one to keep track of the main project and another for mac users to pull certain files from. I might be doing this wrong since I am new to git, but what I want is, basically when I push changes to the main branch, I want the files that are already in the 'macOS' branch to get updated as well. I do not want all the files I push to goto the macOS branch since I only am pushing that to main, and If I have to push files to macOS, I only want the files that are already in that branch to get updated.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is still no, but with the note that *branches* don't *mean anything* in Git.  Git is not really about *branches*, although we use branch names to find commits.  Git is not really about *files* either, although each commit *contains* files.  Git is really all about commits.

A branch name like `main` or `macos` simply indicates that you would like Git to use one specific commit.  The commit you'd like Git to use is the one whose hash ID is stored in that branch name.

That one commit has some set of files.  Checking out *that* commit gets *those files* put into your working tree.  Whatever files were in your working tree due to some *other* commit you had out, are now *removed from your working tree*, because you switched away from that other commit, to this commit.

When you make a *new* commit, this makes a new snapshot of every file that Git knows about (all the *tracked* files).  That new snapshot becomes part of the new commit, and Git now writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the *current branch name*.  Now the name selects *this* commit, rather than that other commit.

If you want some checkout to extract all the files including the macOS-specific ones, all of those files must be *in* that one commit.  If not, they must not.  If they're in some other commit, but not in this commit, Git will remove the files when you switch away from that other commit to this commit.

You never push *files*.  You push *commits*.  Those commits contain the full snapshot of every file.